# Configure Enviroment Variables For Production Node.JS

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy my test Express.js app on Heroku using GitHub for resources and mlab for my database. In development th app doesn't have problems when I pass mLab connection string but in production... How must my production environment look?

Here is my `config.js`:

```
 const env=require('dotenv').config(); 

module.exports = {
    development: {
        port: process.env.PORT|| 3000,
        dbPath: process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
    },
    production: {
        port: process.env.PORT|| 3000,
        dbPath: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_MLAB,
    }
};
```

Comment: "In development app dont have problems when I pass mLab connection string but in production...."—but in production... _what_? Are you getting any error messages? We can't help you if you don't give us any information. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.env` file probably isn't (and shouldn't be) used in production. It [should be ignored in your Git repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file).

This means your production database configuration needs to come from somewhere else. If you're using the [official mLab addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab) you can [access your connection string via the `MONGODB_URI` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri), which the addon sets automatically.

If you're not using the official addon you should [set the appropriate environment variable yourself](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), e.g. via

```
heroku config:set MONGODB_URI=...
```

In either case, make sure the name of the environment variable in your code matches what's set in the environment. Generally there is no need for separate development and production variables since they are set in different environments. I recommend using `MONGODB_URI` everywhere.